# What is the correct java.sql.Types for Oracle's NVARCHAR2

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a column in my database that must store file names that can have non-latin characters. That's why it has NVARCHAR2 data type defined.

I would like to try something like this:

```
sqlParameterSource.registerSqlType("file_name", Types.NVARCHAR);
```

but I have serious doubt if I can use java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR for NVARCHAR2 type.
Can I? If not, what should I use?

Comment: And why do you think that `Types.NVARCHAR` would be wrong?

Comment: Actually I used Types.NVARCHAR and it seems to cause no problems. Maybe Oracle's NVARCHAR2 is a kind of superset of plain NVARCHAR. But this is only my conjecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No is the simple answer:

The types NCHAR and NVARCHAR2 are supported indirectly. There is no corresponding java.sql.Types type (use CHAR), but if your application invokes formOfUse(NCHAR) then these types can be accessed. See "NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, NCLOB and the defaultNChar Property" for details.

See this [link.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/java.101/b10979/ref.htm) for more info.